# Custom CSS numbering alignment

Tags: html, css

Got a problem with this code for ordered list which is formatted with CSS. If a list text goes to 2nd line then the second line is not directly aligned/in bottom of first line. It actually starts from below the number. I have included the code.

HTML:

```
<ol class="custom-counter">
<li>Select the given link. Verify that the given building name matches with the building name on the web page you are directed to.</li>
<li>This is the second item</li>
<li>This is the third item</li>
<li>This is the fourth item</li>
<li>This is the fifth item</li>
<li>This is the sixth item</li>
</ol
```

CSS:

```
 #my-counter{

  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
  #my-counter li{
    counter-increment: start-counter;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }


  #my-counter li::before {
    content: counter(start-counter);
      margin-right: 5px;
      font-size: 80%;
      background-color: #E0E0E0;
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      border-radius: 3px;
  }
```

The above code renders the number list as following:

[Number list not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vRTQ.png)
[image: Number list not aligned]

Comment: Add `padding-left` to the `li` and a corresponding negative `margin-left` for the `:before`.

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use margin-left in negative for :before and padding left for li. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ftfxnd1x/)

```
#my-counter{

  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
  #my-counter li{
    counter-increment: start-counter;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }


  #my-counter li::before {
    content: counter(start-counter);
      margin-right: 5px;
      font-size: 80%;
      background-color: #E0E0E0;
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      border-radius: 3px;
          margin-left: -30px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute;` on `:before` and `position: relative;` on `<li>`

```css
#my-counter{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
#my-counter li{
  counter-increment: start-counter;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#my-counter li::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: counter(start-counter);
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ol id="my-counter">
<li>Select the given link. Verify that the given building name matches with the building name on the web page vVerify that the given building name matches with the building name on the web pag you are directed float: left building name matches with the building name on the web page vVerify that the given building name matches with the building name on the web pag you are directed float: left to.</li>
<li>This is the second item</li>
<li>This is the third item</li>
<li>This is the fourth item</li>
<li>This is the fifth item</li>
<li>This is the sixth item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

## my-counter li::before give him `position:absolute` and   #my-counter li give him `padding-left: 35px;position: relative;`

```
#my-counter{

  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
  #my-counter li{
     counter-increment: start-counter;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 35px;
    position: relative;
    
  }


  #my-counter li::before {
       content: counter(start-counter);
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 80%;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<ol id="my-counter">
<li>Select the given link. Verify that the given building name matches with the building name on the web page vVerify that the given building name matches with the building name on the web pag you are directed to.</li>
<li>This is the second item</li>
<li>This is the third item</li>
<li>This is the fourth item</li>
<li>This is the fifth item</li>
<li>This is the sixth item</li>
</ol>
```